# Invalid login credentials after password change from the form in oracle apex

Tags: authentication, plsql, oracle-apex

I've created a custom Authentication Scheme, using a FUNCTION authenticate(username_in IN VARCHAR2, password_in IN VARCHAR2) RETURN BOOLEAN that returns TRUE if the username/password is correct, and FALSE otherwise + the HASH_PASSWORD function to encrypt the password.
I have a users page and when I modify a user password and try to log-in with the new password, I get the invalid credentials, however the password are the same.
I can only modify the password directly from the database.
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Hard to answer that question with just a description of the problem and no code to go by. "when you modify the password" - have you verified in sql if the function returns true for the username/pwd after the change ? Maybe that is where the problem is ? If you can't get it to work the easiest might be to create a new workspace on apex.oracle.com, reproduce the issue and share the credentials so someone can look at it.

Comment: I figured out that the problem was that I hashed the password 2 times, so it was never the same with the one initial password.

Comment: Great. Please close your question since you answered it yourself.